# How to overload function with a function as parameter?

Tags: typescript

```js
function myFunction(fn: (a: string) => void, value: string): void;
function myFunction(fn: (a: number) => void, value: number): void;
function myFunction(fn: (a: string | number) => void, value: string | number): void {
   // Implementation
}
```

When I'm trying to do that, I have an error "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature." - what is terms of TypeScript is understandable, but how  tofix that signature to make it work?

I know I can do it with generic types, but I wanted to constrain it to number or string only - so implementation with `myFunction<T extends string | number>` should avoided as well.

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense, does it? first two definitions say string|number produces string and then you say string|number produces string|number.

Comment: @digitalniweb - typo - I've edited it now

Comment: why not use `typeof`?

Comment: @AfzalK. could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Why don't you want the *implementation* to be generic?  The call signatures will prevent anyone from calling it in a way you don't like.  The only "safe" subtype of `((a: string) => void) | ((a: number) => void)` is `(a: never) => void` which is uncallable.  Unless you use generics you will find the implementation impossible to write (assuming you call the function) without type assertions.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGY5KN). Personally a generic implementation is the only thing that makes sense to me, so please [edit] to clarify what use case breaks if you do that.

Answer (score -1):

Without generics, lifting `|` out of the parameter type allows those two overloads:

```js
function myFunction(fn: (a: string) => void, value: string): void;
function myFunction(fn: (a: number) => void, value: number): void;
function myFunction(fn: ((a: string) => void) | ((b : number) => void), value: string | number): void {
   // Implementation
}
```

It is also possible with generics to allow `myFunction<string>` and `myFunction<number>` but not `myFunction<string | number>`:

```js
function myFunction<
  T extends (
    (T extends string ? true : false) &
    (T extends number ? true : false)
  ) extends true ? unknown : never
>(fn: (a: T) => void, value: T): void {
   // Implementation
}
```